# www-data access sshfs mount point

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, mount, sshfs

I have an `Apache2` on a `Debian Linux`. I mount a `sshfs` to the directory `/mnt/mountpoint/` (it is mounted on boot time via `/etc/fstab`). It is accessed with a softlink from `/var/www/mountpoint`.

When I access the directory with a browser I get a 403.

As fas as I can see the user `www-data` can not read the directory.

Output of `ls` as `www-data`:

```
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? mountpoint
```

Output of `ls` as `root`:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 aneuschitzer www-data 4.0K Jun  5 16:27
```

My corresponding line in `/etc/fstab`

```
sshfs#reader@targethost:/mnt/mountpoint  /mnt/mountpoint        fuse    ro,noexec,gid=www-data  0 0
```

First I had the options `ro,noexec`, I tried without `noexec`. I have read [How to set up sshfs to use www-data](https://serverfault.com/questions/389161/how-to-set-up-sshfs-to-use-www-data) and tried adding the gid, but it did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the options `allow_other` and/or `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf`. Otherwise only the user who mounted the filesystem can use it. Once you've made the change, unmount and remount the filesystem.